# Syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Tags: postgresql

While creating postgres function it is resulting an error as

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 19: WHERE s.shift_id = shiftid
         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 108

Please Help..

```css
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shiftwisedata_sp(INOut shiftid bigint,InOut userdate date,OUT shift_name character varying (50),OUT from_time character varying(50),OUT to_time character varying(50),OUT cal bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
return query
SELECT userdate, s.shift_name, 
          ('00:00' + (h.hour  * interval '1Hour'):: time) AS from_time,
          ('00:00' + ((h.hour + 1)  * interval '1Hour'):: time) AS to_time,
          COALESCE(r.Readings, 0) AS readings
   FROM   shift_wise s
   CROSS  JOIN (VALUES(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9),
                      (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19),
                      (20), (21), (22), (23)) AS h(hour)
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT SUM(r.param_value) AS Readings
                 FROM   table_1 r
                 WHERE  r.timestamp_col >= CAST(userdate as timestamp without time zone ) + h.hour  * interval '1Hour'
                   AND  r.timestamp_col < CAST(userdate as timestamp without time zone ) + h.hour + 1 * interval '1Hour'
                   ) AS r 
WHERE s.shift_id = shiftid
 AND (s.to_time > s.from_time              AND 
       h.hour >= date_part(HOUR, s.from_time) AND
       h.hour <  date_part(HOUR, s.to_time) 
    OR
      s.to_time < s.from_time AND
         (h.hour >= date_part(HOUR, s.from_time) OR
          h.hour < date_part(HOUR, s.to_time))
       )
      ORDER BY s.to_time;
 
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: not the solution, but: have a look at the generate_series built-in

Comment: `1)` Indeed: `generate_series()` could replace the `values()` list, and `2)` the date/time manipulations could also be scutinized, IMHO. `3)` The `h.hour` looks ugly, but that could be a data modelling problem. `4)` Maybe interval and overlaps could help, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

looks like the syntax error is  LEFT JOIN needs an ON clause before the WHERE

Comment: I am converting SQL stored procedure in postgres and in sql SP i have used OUTER apply so what would be the postgres equivalent for that...actually ON caluse is used in joins for identical column and in my case there is no as such identical column

Comment: I have never used LATERAL before, but from inspection of the query  
I think adding `ON TRUE` before the problematic `WHERE` looks like the medicine you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Working Postgres Function

```css
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shiftwisedata_sp(IN shiftid bigint, INOUT userdate date, OUT shift_name character varying, OUT from_time time without time zone, OUT to_time time without time zone, OUT readings bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
  return query
SELECT userdate, s.shift_name, 
          ('00:00' + (h.hour  * interval '1Hour'):: time) AS from_time,
          ('00:00' + ((h.hour + 1)  * interval '1Hour'):: time) AS to_time,
          COALESCE(r.Readings, 0) AS readings
   FROM   shift_wise s
  CROSS  JOIN (VALUES(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9),
                      (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19),
                      (20), (21), (22), (23)) AS h(hour)
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT CAST(SUM(r.param_value) as bigint) AS Readings
                 FROM   table_1 r
                 WHERE  r.timestamp_col >= (CASt(userdate As timestamp without time zone)  + h.hour  * interval '1Hour')
                   AND  r.timestamp_col < (CASt(userdate As timestamp without time zone) + (h.hour + 1) * interval '1Hour')
                   ) AS r ON TRUE
WHERE s.shift_id = shiftid
 AND (s.to_time > s.from_time              AND 
       h.hour >= Extract(HOUR from CAST(s.from_time as time)) AND
       h.hour <  Extract(HOUR from CAST(s.to_time as time)) 
    OR
      s.to_time < s.from_time AND
         (h.hour >= Extract(HOUR from CAST(s.from_time as time)) OR
          h.hour < Extract(HOUR from CAST(s.to_time as time))
       ))
      ORDER BY s.to_time; 
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```