# ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURN" , PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, sql-function, sql-returning

I am trying to write a function which returns a json data from my table by adding person id . 
I am using pgAdmin 4 for it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.getuserinfo(IN userid bigint DEFAULT 00000, OUT uinfo json)
RETURNS SETOF json
LANGUAGE 'sql'
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
SELECT info into uinfo FROM public.users Where uid=userid;
RETURN uinfo;
$BODY$;
ALTER FUNCTION public.getuserinfo(bigint)
 OWNER TO sun;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.getuserinfo(bigint) TO sun 
WITH GRANT OPTION;
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.getuserinfo(bigint) FROM 
PUBLIC;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.getuserinfo(bigint)
  IS 'gets user info by id';
```

but i am getting this error.[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmylY.png)
i searched on tutorials and another previous post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654911/syntax-error-at-or-near-where)
but got no help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re not telling the function there’s a sequence of things, so it expects only one statement to be there and there’s two. Use `BEGIN` and `END`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.getuserinfo(IN userid bigint DEFAULT 00000, OUT uinfo json)
RETURNS SETOF json
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  SELECT info into uinfo FROM public.users Where uid=userid;
  RETURN uinfo;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Also the language probably should be PL/PGSQL

Comment: i tried that before and it gives
ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 7: SELECT info into uinfo FROM public.users Where uid=userid;
^
error message

Comment: @Axel and you didn’t have semicolon after BEGIN?

Comment: _CREATE FUNCTION public.getuserinfo(IN userid bigint DEFAULT 00000, OUT uinfo json)
    RETURNS json
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  SELECT info into uinfo FROM public.users Where uid=userid;
  RETURN uinfo;
END;
$BODY$;_
this is my code now

Comment: @Axel Also only now realized you have language as sql, it probably should be plpgsql since it’s not just sql statements

Comment: thank you very much @Sami Kuhmonen.
i changed the language and removed the return statement and it is working fie.

Comment: the code is now
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getuserinfo(
 userid bigint DEFAULT 0,
 OUT uinfo json)
    RETURNS json
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
 SELECT info into uinfo FROM public.users Where uid=userid;
END;
$BODY$;
`

Comment: `return` is not acceptable in `setof` returning functions. Should be `return next` or `return query`.

Comment: LANGUAGE plpgsql was critical change for me . i had earlier LANGUAGE sql, which was giving error.